# how to add string to messageFormat in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a string to this line so it can translate to other languages. What way can i code a String into this so "ships" can be translated?

```
private void nrLikes(final TextView likes, String postid) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes")
            .child(postid);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            likes.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0} ships", dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to find his location, his country.

Second, you have to do: Values/String file for every language you want, there to add the strings you wish and then call them in your code. It’s really sisyphean, I’m sure that there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can see from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Usually how we translate is through strings.xml

```
<string name="message">%1$s ships</string>
```

In this example, the format string has one argument: %1$s is a string

Then you can do the following:

```
String text = getString(R.string.message, dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
```